# d3.js Insert() function adds child element - instead of a sibling element

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, d3.js

It looks like when I use the “insert” function, the new element is always inserted as a child – Not as a **sibling**.

I still don't understand why this is, since the insert function should actually insert a new element before the specified element - and not **in** the specified element as a child.

Basically I am trying to create a "rect" element next to the "text" elements

The goal is to put a background color behind my texts in my d3 sankey diagram.

```
 // NODE TEXT
this.nodes
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(this.data.nodes)
  .join(
    (enter) =>
      enter
        .append('text')
        .text((d) => `${d.name + ': ' + d.value}`)
        .style('fill', '#000000')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'right')
        .attr('x', (d, i) => {
          return d.x0 + (d.x1 - d.x0) / 0.5;
        })
        .attr('y', (d, i) => {
          return d.y0 + (d.y1 - d.y0) / 2;
        })
        .attr('dy', '0.35em')
        .attr('transform', (d, i) => {
          const x = d.x0 + (d.x1 - d.x0) / 2;
          const y = d.y0 + (d.y1 - d.y0) / 2;
          return `rotate(0, ${x}, ${y})`;
        })
        .call(getTextBox)
        .insert('rect', 'text')
        .attr('width', function (d) {
          return d.bbox.width;
        })
        .attr('height', function (d) {
          return d.bbox.height;
        })
        .attr('x', function (d) {
          return d.bbox.x;
        })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
          return d.bbox.y;
        })
        .style('fill', 'grey'),
    (update) =>
      update
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .ease(d3_easeQuadInOut)
        .attr('x', (d, i) => {
          return d.x0 + (d.x1 - d.x0) / 2;
        })
        .attr('y', (d, i) => {
          return d.y0 + (d.y1 - d.y0) / 2;
        })
        .attr('transform', (d, i) => {
          const x = d.x0 + (d.x1 - d.x0) / 2;
          const y = d.y0 + (d.y1 - d.y0) / 2;
          return `rotate(0, ${x}, ${y})`;
        })
  );


function getTextBox(selection) {
  selection.each(function (d) {
    d.bbox = this.getBBox();
  });
}
```

Here is a picture of the rendered HTML elements from my browser.

Notice that the “rect” element is a child of the text and not a sibling as desired.

[image: HTML Elements]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result in the code you have is expected: it happens because the `insert` is called on a selection of texts, which acts as a parent.

The first, simple solution, is breaking the chain, so you have a `selection.append` and a `selection.insert`. For instance:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg"),
  data = d3.range(5).map(e => ({
    value: e
  }));

svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .join(enter => {
    enter.append("text")
      .attr("x", 20)
      .attr("y", d => 20 + 30 * d.value)
      .text(d => `text #${d.value}`)
      .call(getTextBox);

    enter.insert("rect", "text")
      .attr('width', d => d.bbox.width)
      .attr('height', d => d.bbox.height)
      .attr('x', d => d.bbox.x)
      .attr('y', d => d.bbox.y)
      .style('fill', 'grey')

  })

function getTextBox(selection) {
  selection.each(function(d) {
    d.bbox = this.getBBox();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

However, this SVG will have this structure:

```
<rect></rect>
<rect></rect>
<rect></rect>
...
<text></text>
<text></text>
<text></text>
...
```

That said, if you want the following structure instead...

```
<rect></rect>
<text></text>
<rect></rect>
<text></text>
<rect></rect>
<text></text>
...
```

... you'll need a bit more elaborated `insert`. In this example I'm getting the respective text elements by their IDs:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg"),
  data = d3.range(5).map(e => ({
    value: e
  }));

svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .join(enter => {
    enter.append("text")
      .attr("id", d => `text${d.value}`)
      .attr("x", 20)
      .attr("y", d => 20 + 30 * d.value)
      .text(d => `text #${d.value}`)
      .call(getTextBox);

    enter.insert("rect", d => d3.select(`#text${d.value}`).node())
      .attr('width', d => d.bbox.width)
      .attr('height', d => d.bbox.height)
      .attr('x', d => d.bbox.x)
      .attr('y', d => d.bbox.y)
      .style('fill', 'grey')

  })

function getTextBox(selection) {
  selection.each(function(d) {
    d.bbox = this.getBBox();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is precisely the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over data & bind both text/rect in parent wrapper

Hope this helps : [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-sntmw9?file=index.js)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Unfortunately, the example doesn't help because I need the text elements first to get the values (x, y, width, height) for the new rect elements. 

The rects should be rendered directly behind the texts. Therefore, I need to read them first.