# Smarter way of chaining SVG operations in this example?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

In the following code, I create text svg elements, word-wrap it and then create bounding boxes based on the new (wrapped) text dimensions and recntagles. I was only able do it in the following way, and I would like to know if the code could not be simplified so that maybe the boxes are created in the same function as the text?

```
 var a=settings.g.selectAll(".axislabel")
                .data(featureData)
                .join(
                    enter => enter.append("text")
                        .attr("x", d => d.label_coord.x)
                        .attr("y", d => d.label_coord.y)
                        .text(d => d.name)
                        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
                        .call(wrap, 60)
                )
    
    var x=settings.g.selectAll("text")
/getting the elements I just created
    for(let a of x['_groups'][0])
    {
        //iterating through and create bounding boxes
        var v=a.getBBox();
       //createing rectangles based on the boundinx boxes
        settings.g.selectAll("labelBack")
        .data([a.textContent])
        .join(
            enter => enter.append("rect")
                .attr("x", v.x)
                .attr("y", v.y)
                .attr("width", v.width)
                .attr("height", v.height)
                .attr("fill", "white")
                        .attr("opacity", 1)
                        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                        .attr("stroke", "black")
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `selection.join` with a functional argument, the function that you pass in constructs the dom element you want. Thus, you've got a lot of flexibility in what you build. In particular, you can do something like

```
enter => {
  let g = enter.append("g");
  let rect = g.append("rect");
  let text = g.append("text")
     ...Code to set the text
  rect
    .attr('height', ...Code to set the height)
    .attr('width', ...Code to set the width)
```

This can work because the text was set by the time the rect is sized.  You can see this in action in the code below.

Credit: While this is a little bit different, I based the code partly on [Gerardo's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76249856#76253136).

```js
  let pad = 2;
  let w = 200;
  let h = 100;
  let svg = d3
    .select('#viz')
    .append("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, w, h])
    .style("max-width", `${640}px`)
    .style('border', 'solid 1px black');
    
   let data = [
    { x: 10, y: 20, text: "This" },
    { x: 56, y: 50, text: "should" },
    { x: 120, y: 20, text: "work" }
  ];

  svg
    .append("g")
    .selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .join((enter) => {
      let g = enter.append("g");
      let rect = g.append("rect");
      let text = g
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", (d) => d.x)
        .attr("y", (d) => d.y)
        .text((d) => d.text)
        .call(wrap);
      rect
        .attr("x", (d) => d.x - pad)
        .attr("y", (d) => d.y - d.bbox.height + 2 * pad)
        .attr("width", (d) => d.bbox.width + 2 * pad)
        .attr("height", (d) => d.bbox.height + 2 * pad)
        .attr("fill", "#ddd")
        .attr("stroke", "black");
    });

  function wrap(selection) {
    selection.each(function (d) {
      d.bbox = this.getBBox();
    });
  }
```

```html
<div id="viz"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```